# Class for remembering the length of data and split them up vb.net

Tags: vb.net, function, class, properties

Good morning,
I'm still a beginner with Visual Basic, but right now I'm stuck in creating my program.

In my program I read an XML document in by means of XElement.Load.
I have to use a class that contains a number of properties, among other things, to remember and align the maximum length of the various data (Name and Country).
Here I have to create a function in a class that splits the rule into separate parts and aligns it.

I just have no idea how to align the maximum length and how to retrieve this function in the form class.

My program so far:

**Form 1**

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click  
  
Public Persons As XElement  
Dim myNameLength As New LayoutClass  
  
  
If Persons Is Nothing Then  
  
TextBox1.Text = "no person was found"  
        Else  
            Dim queryData = From Person In Persons.Descendants("Person")  
                Where (Person.Attribute("Name")).Value <> ""  
             Select Naam = Person.Attribute("Name").Value,  
             Country= Person.Attribute("Country").Value  
             Order By (Name)  
  
TextBox1.Text = " "  
TextBox1.Text = "The persons are: " & vbCrLf & myNameLength.PersonNameLength  
  
End sub
```

**Layout Class:**

```
Public Class LayoutClass  
  
Public Property NameLength() As Short  
  
  
  
Public Function PersonNameLength() As Short  
  
        Dim PersonLength As Short  
  
        If PersonLength > PersonNameLengthThen  
  
            PersonNameLength= PersonLength  
  
        End If  
  
        Return PersonNameLength  
  
    End Function
```

Can you please help me on my way?

Comment: it's not clear to me. What happened to querydata? You have on your textbox1 "The persons are:" and i expected querydata.Count.Tostring(), instead you have a function that retrieve the length from myNameLength which value is never assigned. I'm confused

Comment: Could you maybe post a sample of the xml your loading.  Would also be helpful here if you could post some code that would actually compile, they are a few syntax errors there.  And just to clarify, what exactly is your intended output here, is it just to get a count of names that match your criteria?